# how to create a jquery mobile listview from displaying data from mysql database using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I am creating a web app that should insert jobs into the database for logged in users, after you click a job on the listview,a page is displayed showing the jobs,city,details then you have two buttons,apply and favorites,apply works just fine,favorites insert the selected job into a table and write it to another page "favorite" in a listview using php,It does write it but all the job selected by a specific user as favorite appear on a single listview block and i also want to create a link to the job file that specify all the details about that job.

```
Here are my Jquery and my PHP codes

<div data-role="page" id="page6" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Favorites</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
     <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"picture-upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']);  
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","recruitment");
$q=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET image='".$_FILES['file']['name']."'where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

}
?>
       <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
        <h5><span>
        <div id="box1">
        <input name="file" id="file" class="hidden" type="file" ><br>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" data-role="none">Upload picture</button>
         <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","recruitment");
$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users where username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    /*echo $row['username'].'<br>';*/
if($row['image']==""){
    echo'<img id="profile-image" width="50" height="50" src="picture-upload/defaultimage.png" alt="Default profile picture">';
}
    else{
    echo'<img id="profile-image" width="50" height="50" src="picture-upload/'.$row['image'].'" alt="Profile picture">';


}
}

?>

        </div>
         </br></span>

        <?php  echo 'Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'];

        echo "<br><a href='logout.php' data-ajax='false'>Logout</a>"; ?> ...</h5> 
        <?php
//login.php
include_once 'Dbconnect.php'; 
$JobUser=$_SESSION['username'];
// Select the database.
mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$sql="select * from favorites where username='$JobUser'";
$record=mysql_query($sql);


?>
     <div id="output"></div>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  data-filter="true" id="list_jobs">
      <li data-role="list-divider">
      <?php
while($users=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$users['jobid']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$users['jobcity']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$users['jobtitle']."</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
exit;
?>
      </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy;2016 &bull; Genesis M&C Holdings Pty</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something. Mixing `mysqli` and the deprecated `mysql_*` functions is extremely problematic.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks,i will fix that right away.